# Riemann Sum relation to Riemann Integral

Tags: calculus

Explain why the limit of a Riemann sum of a function is equal to the antiderivative a function evaluated at the endpoints (assuming it's a definite integral). Does this tutor's explanation (highlighted) make sense? Could you explain it to me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9QoJ.png)

Comment: 1. This is actually quite nontrivial when it comes down to it: this is the fundamental theorem of calculus. 2. It is easiest to understand by considering an image which is in every calculus text, which argues that $\int_x^{x+h} f(y) dy$ is approximately $h f(x)$ if $h$ is small. It's hard to be intuitively convincing without showing this picture.

Comment: I'd tend to say no, the tutor's explanation doesn't make that much sense. Everything he says is true, but there's very little explanation of why it's true. Now, it seems like this is from a site that's offering help with calculus or something? "Prove the fundamental theorem of calculus" is really a much harder question than one would expect the tutor to have to deal with...

Answer (score 1):

This is true because of two things. First the definition of the definite integral as the limit over all partitions of the Riemann sums (approximation of the area under a curve). Really it is the limit over limits of overshooting the value and undershooting the values, taking maxima and minima of your function, but if this is confusing, just thinking about it as a limit over rectangles with tinier and tinier bases.

Second, is the is a combination of both fundamental theorem's of calculus. If $F'(x)=f(x)$ for any $x$ in some interval $(a,b)$ then we get that:
$$
\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(x)|_a^b=F(b)-F(a)
$$